# JQuery click binding and Facebook JS SDK weirdness

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, facebook, click

I have an app that uses the FB javascript SDK to load pics via ajax. It all works, but when the user clicks on the image and it is successfully uploaded, I want to unbind clicking on it so the user cannot upload it again.

The function looks like this:

```
function postImage(fbimgurl, token, obj) {

obj.click(false); //I think this should turn off clicking but it does not 

$.ajax({

       //ajax code here. This works fine

}
```

It is initially bound when the Facebook connect is successful when the page loads:

```
FB.getLoginStatus(function (response) {

   if (response.status =='connected') {

var fbaccesstoken = response.authResponse.accessToken;

 $('.pic').each(function(){  
  var picurl = $(this).attr('fullurl'); 
  $(this).on('click', function() { postImage(picurl, fbaccesstoken, $(this)) }); 
});

}
```

I suspect that the 'connected' response is being called again after I upload the image so it re-binds the postImage function. Am I correct? I have tried to bind this function to the pic divs elsewhere in the script but it only seems to work if I put it inside the Facebook response, maybe because of the access token or some other asynchronous stuff I don't understand. What is the best way to unbind this object when the function is successful so it cannot be re-clicked?

Answer (score 0):

you could unbind from inside your click handler function by using the target on the event object.

```
$('.pic').each(function(){  
  var picurl = $(this).attr('fullurl'); 
  $(this).on('click', function( event ) { 
      postImage(picurl, fbaccesstoken, $(this));
      $(event.target).unbind('click');  
  }); 
});
```

Comment: unfortunately, that does not work either. I can only guess the facebook connect rebinds the click event handler. This is frustrating.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out by putting obj.off() in the function. For some reason doing it with 'click' failed. Weird.